# AppleScript delete file if not used/opended last 365 days

Tags: applescript

How to write/is it possible to write AppleScript, which will delete files in certain folder, if the file wasn't used/opened for a certain amount of time?

Comment: Does it need to be AppleScript? Or is any scripting solution ok?

Comment: You should look at the [`find`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) _command_ in Terminal as it can do exactly what you're asking without the need for AppleScript. That said, you can use the `do shell script` _command_ in AppleScript to run the `find` _command_ if you have some need/reason to do it that way.

Comment: @patrix Any scripting solution would be ok. Prefer not to install any additional soft